# Android.XML. Large radio group all not fitting to screen

Tags: android, xml, size, screen

I have set landscape orientation and the last button (the eighth) of my app is not fitting on 4" screen for my samsung mini S3. It fits on larger screensizes on the emulator. Ive tried setting the parent to a fixed size, the radio buttons seem to spread out more when on the actual device. Any ideas?

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#111111"
android:gravity="left"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/RadioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioButtonlowC1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:button="@drawable/my_radio"
        android:checked="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioButtonD1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:button="@drawable/my_radio" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioButtonE1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:button="@drawable/my_radio" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioButtonF1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:button="@drawable/my_radio" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioButtonG1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:button="@drawable/my_radio" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioButtonA1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:button="@drawable/my_radio" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioButtonB1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:button="@drawable/my_radio" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioButtonC1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:button="@drawable/my_radio" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap relative layout with scrollview

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

         <RelativeLayout 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#111111"
           android:gravity="left" >

           <!-- your stuff -->

           </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion I found a working solution just now, if I use scroll view it allows me to scroll down to see the button thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: If you found your answer accept it or post it so that others can refer to it latter